# How can I get creatives(ads post) from facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api, instagram-graph-api

How can I get all ads posts from Instagram and Facebook?

Facebook Library ads allow to get only POLITICAL_AND_ISSUE_ADS.
Facebook graph api doesn`t allow to get creatives from other accounts.

May there be another ways? Or can I get some permission for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just get 'all' the ads. Either you get the ones in the Ad Library, or you get permissions for a specific Ad Account.

If you are authorized to access an Ad Account you can use the [Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v18.0). The basic idea is to fetch an account's [Ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/#overview) with `/act_{your-account-id}/ads` and for each ad, its [Creatives](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/#overview) `/{ad-id}/creatives`. Creatives have fields such as `object_id` and `effective_instagram_media_id`, which are the actual Facebook and Instagram posts.